# Selenium / Python - how to mock server responses?

Tags: python, selenium, mocking

I've written a tool that automates interaction with a slow web service that's outside of my control. In order to test certain features, I'd like to avoid Selenium making repeated requests to the real service. For this I wanted to use unit tests and mocking.

Is there a way to mock out responses from a real server? Ideally I'd like to be able to define a mapping of:

```
mock_responses = {
  'http://server/path1': 'path1.html',
  'http://server/pathN': 'pathN.html',
}
```

so that when the URL in key is requested, instead of issuing a real request, Selenium would just treat the local static HTML file as if it came from the live web service.

PS. I'm not looking for solutions involving standing up a test webserver returning static pages.

Comment: you can setup fiddler to mock all responds

Answer (score 0):

As you are planning to keep local copy of static htmls (responses), you can load required response html as and when required using Selenium (webdriver) `get()` method.

For example, you have stored all the response HTMLs in "C:/responces/" (you can store response htmls as part of your automation framework), then you can load required response as below:

```
driver.get("file://C:/responces/path1.html");
driver.get("file://C:/responces/pathN.html");
```